# Configure the print of the browser with printArea Ask a question

Tags: jquery, html

would like to know if you can change the print settings in the browser from my printArea code ([options]):

Configuration to change:

- Destination (printer to choose)
- Pages (number of pages I need)
- do you copy
- Design (Horizontal vertical printing orientation)
- Paper size
- Pages by leaves
- Margins
- Quality
- Scale
- Configuration (Header and Footer, Double-sided, Background Graphics)

I have looked for examples but I do not see any.

This change must be made from the code at the time of printing so that the user does not have to configure manual browser printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css to configure what is printed (`@media print {..}`), the styling of pages (`@page {..}`), where page breaks should occur (`break-after`, `break-before`, etc.), and many other properties of the document (see https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/ for a good overview).

There is no javascript/html/css interface to the printer properties however, so destination, probably pages to print, print quality, etc. is only under end-user control.